# Turn off/on android screen

Tags: android, screen, brightness

I am trying to turn the android screen off and then on again, after a few seconds. The "turn off" part works, with this code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParam = getWindow().getAttributes();
oldBrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)/255f;
layoutParam.screenBrightness = 0; 
layoutParam.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParam);
```

But then, when I try to turn the screen on again, it does not work with this code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParam = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParam.screenBrightness = oldBrightness;
layoutParam.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParam);
```

Any idea to solve that ?

thanks

Comment: When, debugging, did you check if the `oldBrightness` value ?

Answer (score 1):

I think U can try Powermanager WakeLock maybe it will work. I m using this code in my application. and it works well.  :)

Also u need to set permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/> // Manifest Permission

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
                WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                                                 | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP
                                                 | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
                wakeLock.acquire();
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, are you sure about the "/255f" in this line:

```
oldBrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)/255f;
```

What is the value in "oldBrightness" when you get/set it ?

Maybe you could try this:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock lck = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "tag");
lck.acquire();
```

The normal wake lock doesn't turn the screen on but causes it to stay on when a user causes it. But this flag forces the screen to turn on immediately. It requires the  "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK".

More about it:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

And the screen properties (on, off, bright, dim, etc.):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

Comment: android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN... return a value between 0 and 255, and layoutParam.screenBrightness wait for 0 and 1.

With your code the screen is turned on only if I shut it down manually, not with my code. So I try to use a wake lock to turn off also, but it does not turn off like this:

PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) SecureStopwatchExecActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
           PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "tag");
    wl.acquire();
    wl.release();